# Access point in nexus 7 and nexus 10 issue

Tags: android, wifi, ip-address, access-point

I'm developing an app that needs that the device creates an access point. I'm testing the code on a Nexus 7 (Android 4.2.1) and a Nexus 10 (4.2.2) and I get the same problem in both. I manage to enable the access point but every device that tries to connect stays "Obtaining ip address". Any idea why? I tested the same code in a galaxy tab 10" (Android 4.0.3) and it works perfect.

```
private void createWifiAccessPoint(String pSSID)
{    
    if(mWifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
    {
        mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);          
    }

    Method[] wmMethods = mWifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();   
    boolean methodFound=false;
    for(Method method: wmMethods){
        if(method.getName().equals("setWifiApEnabled"))
        {
            methodFound=true;

            WifiConfiguration netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
            netConfig.SSID = pSSID;

            try {
                boolean apstatus = (Boolean) method.invoke(mWifiManager, netConfig,true);          
                for (Method isWifiApEnabledmethod: wmMethods)
                {
                    if(isWifiApEnabledmethod.getName().equals("isWifiApEnabled"))
                    {
                        while(!(Boolean)isWifiApEnabledmethod.invoke(mWifiManager)){
                        };
                        for(Method method1: wmMethods){
                            if(method1.getName().equals("getWifiApState")){
                                int apstate;
                                apstate=(Integer)method1.invoke(mWifiManager);
                                Toast.makeText(this, netConfig.SSID + String.valueOf(apstate), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(apstatus)
                {
                    System.out.println("success");  
                }else
                {
                    System.out.println("failed");   
                }

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }      
    }
    if(!methodFound){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that the device you are trying to connect with is expected to be supplied with an IP address etc, from the DHCP server in the Nexus device. Your code is just creating an access point. You probably need a static IP address on both ends of the link. That said, I'm not sure how that should be done, as I have more or less exactly the same problem myself.

See [Unable to programatically create working Wi-Fi access point on Jellybean tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050143/unable-to-programatically-create-working-wi-fi-access-point-on-jellybean-tablet)

I have attempted to associate an IP address with the access point, and although I appear to have done that, I have still been unable to establish a connection so I only have a partial answer to your question I'm afraid.